# Send range via fetch for streaming

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming

I'm developing a streaming algorithm, as I needed to send an authorization header I can't use the source of the video tag, so I'm using a fetch for that, but that makes me unable to send the header of the range. How could I do this? I've researched a lot but I can't find anything.

```
const result = await fetch('http://' + oca.data.ocaURL + "/range/" + content.data.streamID, {
     headers: {
         "Authorization": getCookie("session"),
         "Range": "bytes=0-"
     }
  });
  const blob = await result.blob();
  if (blob) {
    setContentURL(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  } else {
    console.warn("Can not load");
  }
  ...
  <VideoContainer controls poster={posterURL}>
      <VideoSource src={contentURL}></VideoSource>
  </VideoContainer>
```

Comment: You could do the fetching of each range yourself, and MediaSource Extensions.  Probably far easier though to include the authentication in the URL.  (Sure is too bad the powers-that-be got rid of our basic/digest auth specification in the URL!  Or that they arbitrarily disable service workers, or this would be a lot easier.)